# Best practices organizing multi-tier application on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to have some suggestions about the best practices to organize my project using Docker.

Lets say I have project X which is composed of two main applications, Store and a Product Management Application. They are completely different application but are part of the same project. They have its own services, source code, repository and infrastructure.

Store [mysql, mongodb, elasticsearch, nginx, php, app source code]
PMA [mysql, nginx, php, app source code]

Since they are two different repositories and have their own docker-compose file, how can I run everything with just one command?

Should I create a docker repo that extends both docker-compose and run everything in just one go?

Answer (score 0):

- Isolate things as much as possible, so if you need a mysql and a
  mongodb separate them, and make the containers as small as possible,
  with only the libraries and binaries they need (aka
  [microcontainers](https://www.iron.io/microcontainers-tiny-portable-containers/)). To achieve this you can also build your images
  using [alpine linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).
- For database containers use volumes to store the data in the host
  instead of the container, works faster. You can also store the configuration files in a volume so you don't have to access the container each time you want to change a configuration.
- Use Dockefiles and instead of building your images manually, this makes
  images replicable in any host, and you can store them in git.
- Use docker compose to build and run all containers at once.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't recommend containerizing the databases. There aren't a lot of good use cases as that much replication just chews through IO and disk utilization on a few hosts. You also lose a lot of typical specialization and maintenance / management for the database / datastores.

Create a git repository of your Dockerfiles. It makes updating systems far easier in the future. My structure is normally

```
/Dockerfiles
    /Project
        Dockerfile
        (required files)
        docker-compose.yml
```

Also have a private registry, but build those images from the above dockerfiles. Makes managing versions infinitely easier and facilitates devops and automated deployments.

1. Create a swarm cluster (1 or more hosts)
2. Create Two overlay networks (named store and pma if you like)
3. Create a shared NFS storage point to be mounted to the hosts at /docker. Mountpoint needs to be at read, write, and execute for the docker group. This will be used for persistent storage on the elasticsearch cluster
4. Create services on the store network for php-fpm (to run the source code), NGINX to proxy it, and elastic search. They can refer to each other on the overlay network by name
5. Create services on the pma network for php-fpm, nginx (proxy)

You could also just create apache/php images. That's what we do for beadockstar/laravel.

Be mindful of storage on the PHP systems. If you ever need to upload something that is *not* going to be abstracted away to a CDN of some sort, you need to make sure the directory the uploads are going to is persisted onto the /docker host directory (or any other uniform host directory across all swarm hosts)